# Getting accurate length for custom dash pattern in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, symbology

I try to set a custom dash pattern for simple line using QGIS 3.4. Both my project and layer are in a projected CRS using meter as unit (EPSG:2154, layer are stored as Multilinestring in a geopackage).

This dash pattern should display a repeating 1.5 meter dash followed by a 5 meter blank space. I set my symbology unit as "Meters at Scale" (I also did try with "Meters" as unit with the exact same result) and use a custom dash pattern with [1.5;5] value.

As you can see in the image below the dash are rendered as 0.9m and the space between the dash mesure around 3.3m (as I'm measuring 3 dash and 2 space the total length should be 14,5m the measuring tool give a total of 9.5m). I try changing Cap style between flat and square, checking/unchecking the "Clip Feature to Canvas Extent" option and using different ellipsoid for measurement (the one associated with my CRS and none/Planimetric) but none of that give me a dash pattern close to 1.5m/5m.

[image]

Is this a bug still present in QGIS 3.4 (I find some related bug for the old QGIS version 2) or is there a way to get accurate dash pattern ?

Comment: Have you tried using `map units`? How far from the "center" of your CRS area are your lines?

Comment: @Erik map units give exactly the same result, I'm a few hundred km from the center of CRS but using an ellipsoid for measuring should compensate...